# Angular: async pipe and drawing svg

Tags: angular, d3.js

Consider the following component

```
export class SvgGraphComponent {
    public svgData$: Observable<ISomeType>

    constructor(private svgGraphService: SvgGraphService) {
        this.svgData$ = this.svgGraphService.getData();

        this.svgData$.pipe(
            // adding takeUntil here
            // delay(0)
        ).subscribe((svgData: ISomeType) => this.drawSvg(svgData))
    }

    private drawSvg(svgData: ISomeType) {
        const element: HTMLElement = (d3.select('#svgChart').node() as HTMLElement);
        if (!element) {
            return;
        }

        // drawing here
    }
}
```

The template is the following

```
<div id="svgChart" *ngIf="(svgData$ | async) as svgData"></div>
```

The reason why I'm doing this is that I want to show spinner while data is being uploaded. Still `drawSvg` seem to get value before async pipe and for that reason `element` is `null`. If I uncomment `delay(0)` everything seems to be OK here. Still I don't like delays. Is there a way to make sure that subscription in constructor will be processed after async pipe (tried to put subscription in `ngAfterViewInit` and got the same result). Maybe there's totally different way to organize this stuff?

*PS.* Angular version is 11.2 and yes, I'm using d3 to draw graph

Comment: Where are you using the `drawSvg` method?

Comment: Thank you! I've forgot to add `subscribe` in this simplified code snippet

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `async` and `subscribe` at the same time since they're doing the same thing. I'd suggest simply to change your observable code like this:

```js
  constructor(private svgGraphService: SvgGraphService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loader = true
    this.svgGraphService.getData().subscribe((svgData: ISomeType) => {
      this.loader = false;
      this.drawSvg(svgData)
    })
  }

  private drawSvg(svgData: ISomeType) {
      const element: HTMLElement = (d3.select('#svgChart').node() as HTMLElement);
      if (!element) {
          return;
      }

      // drawing here
  }
```

```html
<loader *ngIf="loader"></loader>
<div id="svgChart" [hidden]="loader"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using `async` and `subscribe` on different observables. Using `map` will mean that `drawSvg` will be called before `div` will be added on async pipe emition, that's not an option

Comment: "I'm using async and subscribe on different observables" No you don't, according to your question. It's the same field: `svgData$`. And `map` will only get "processed" on the successful resolve of the subscription with the `async` pipe

Comment: unfortunately, `map` is not a solution anyway, cause if I use map `drawSvg` will be called before `#svgChart` div will be added

Comment: ohh okay I see. Then actually using subscribe is a better choice than `async` for this case.

Comment: I've updated my answer, tell me if it works

Comment: sorry for a delay with this aswer. Your solution should definitelly work, still I try to avoid using data in properties, cause I'm using `onPush`, I'll add more info in my question and will start a bounty. Thank you for your answer!